# Serializing an emacs lisp hash to file

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs lisp, is there a way to serialize a hash table to a file in and then reading it again at a later time?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easily possible since Emacs 23.2 or so. Check with

```
(featurep 'hashtable-print-readable)
```

If this returns `t`, you can simply `prin1` a hashtable to a buffer, save it and `read` it later.

Comment: ok maybe I should ask another question, because the hash i want to save contains a common lisp structure, defined using `defstruct`. Is there anyway to serialize an hash table containing cl structs? Thanks

Comment: `defstruct` objects are just vectors, they will serialize with no problems.

Comment: For example, http://pastie.org/4376530
This does not serialize properly, when I try to read it with `read` I get an error.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with hash tables or defstructs, but with window configurations. They indeed do not serialize (see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configuration-Type.html).

Comment: Ok, is it possible to decompose a window configuration into something serializable?